# Create list of generated vectors

Tags: r, vector, generator

Let's say I have a function that accepts a vector of parameters and returns a vector of results (of the same length). And let's say I want to call this function 100 times always with the same parameter - a 100 elements long vector of 1 - ideally getting a list of vectors as a result.

The first thing that came to my mind was to use lapply, specifically to call lapply on a list of vectors. My testing on smaller data proved that it should work and that it returns data in required format. The problem is that I'm unable to generate the list of vectors I need as the argument.

All I found online was how to generate a vector which doesn't help me much as I already know how to do that. The problem is how to generate a list out of these vectors `(using list(rep(1, 100), rep(1, 100), ...)` is out of question as I'd have to repeat the `rep(1, 100)` part a hundred times.

Comment: To make sure I've read your question correctly: you want a list of 100 repeats of `rep(1, 100)`, or the equivalent?

Comment: Yes, that's what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quickest way to do this is to use R's built in `replicate` function, like so:

```
replicate(100, rep(1, 100), simplify = FALSE)
```

where `rep(1, 100)` gets replaced by the vector you actually want a list of 100 copies of. An equivalent statement would be to use `lapply` and an anonymous function, like so:

```
lapply(1:100, function(x){ rep(1, 100) })
```

Essentially, what this is doing is writing a function that takes its input, throws it away, and outputs your vector of choice. In fact, that's not much different than what `replicate` does under the hood, according to the documentation:

> replicate is a wrapper for the common use of sapply for repeated evaluation of an expression

The only difference from the standard use of `replicate` is that, by default, `replicate` returns your list of vectors simplified to an array. But as you can see it's easy enough to force it not to do that by passing `simplify = FALSE`.